# With LINQ how do you return a string const in the result from the select operator

Tags: linq, linqpad

In LinqPad I have the following query statements...

```
var genre = "Anime & Animation";
var minRating = 3.0;
var topNum = 30;

var query = 
    (from g in Genres
    from t in g.Titles 
    where g.Name==genre
    && t.Instant.Available==true
    && t.AverageRating >= minRating
    orderby t.AverageRating descending 
    select new {t.Name, t.Rating, t.AverageRating, t.ShortSynopsis}).Take(topNum);

query.Dump(string.Format("Top {0} {1} Instant Watch Movies with a {2:0.0} minimum average rating sorted by average rating in descending order.",topNum,genre,minRating));
```

I want to return the genre string variable in the result set.

Another way to ask, with TSQL I would do "SELECT field1, field2, 'Action & Adventure' as genre from MyTitles".  So how do you do that in Linq.

Seth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify additional members of the anonymous type by adding `PropertyName = <value>`, so if you want to add a property `Genre` with some constant value, you can write:

```
new { t.Name, t.Rating, t.AverageRating, 
      t.ShortSynopsis, Genre = "Action & Adventure" }
```

The value of genre will be probably the same as the `genre` variable or the property `g.Name` in your query, so you could use this property (instead of string literal):

```
new { t.Name, t.Rating, t.AverageRating, 
      t.ShortSynopsis, Genre = g.Name } // Or 'Genre = genre'
```

It is worth noting that if you just use some property name in the construction of anonymous type (e.g. `t.Name`), it is just a shortcut for writing `Name = t.Name` (the compiler copies the property name automatically).

Comment: Have you checked the SQL Translation of that? How can i make it to return the string also in the SQL tab ??